# Stacked hue histogram

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I don't have the reputation to add inline images I'm sorry.

This is the code I found:

```
bins = np.linspace(df.Principal.min(), df.Principal.max(), 10)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Gender", hue="loan_status", palette="Set1", col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.hist, 'Principal', bins=bins, ec="k")
g.axes[-1].legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

I want to do something similar with some data I have:

```
bins = np.linspace(df.overall.min(), df.overall.max(), 10)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="player_positions", hue="preferred_foot", palette="Set1", col_wrap=4)
g.map(plt.hist, 'overall', bins=bins, ec="k")
g.axes[-1].legend()
plt.show()
```

The hue "preferred_foot" is just left and right.

My output:

[image]

I am not sure why I can't see the left values on the plot

```
df['preferred_foot'].value_counts()
Right    13960
Left      4318
```

Comment: Here's where you get your [information](https://rawnote.dinhanhthi.com/files/ibm/final_project). You can check if the 'Right' appears in the graphs of the two types of 'Principal' and 'age' that you are using as a reference here, and Did you? We would get more answers if we had that and publicly available data to isolate the obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure those are not stacked histograms, but just two histograms one behind the other. I believe your "left" red bars are simply hidden behind the "right" blue bars.

You could try adding some `alpha=0.5` or changing the order of the hues (add `hue_order=['Right','Left']` to the call to FacetGrid.

Comment: `hue_order=['Right','Left']` this worked the exact way I intended, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that these histograms are NOT stacked, contrary to the title of the question